# My Google-Places API Key is activated but not working

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-places-api

I'm using [this package](https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places) to run Google Places API on Python. I'm running the following code:

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang
key='XXXXXXX'
google_places = GooglePlaces(key)

query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
    location='London, England', keyword='Fish and Chips',
    radius=20000, types=[types.TYPE_FOOD])

print(query_result)
```

However when I do that, I get this error:

```
{
   "error_message" : "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/geocoding_backend?project=_",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

However my API is enabled and everything seems cool, as you can see below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Can someone help here?

Comment: Did you authorize the key for your application?

Comment: @MrUpsidown by the images it seems that yes I did, however I'm not sure if I need some authorization that I'm not aware.

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6310037?hl=en please check this and especially the **Restrict your API keys to be used by only the IP addresses, referrer URLs, and mobile apps that need them** and make sure your key is not restricted to a different IP/domain (referrers). If it's not and it still doesn't work, I'd suggest to generate a new key and try again. So click on manage (Gerenciar), then on "credentials" on the left, then edit the key and check the application restrictions.